# Change array index to integer in ruby code

Tags: ruby, arrays

From this command, I can get array index but I can use this index as integer

```
index=strInput.each_index.select{|i| strInput[i] == subInput}.map(&:to_i)
    puts (index)
```

When in print output, it show with bucket like [15]

And when I try to use index directly like

```
puts scores[index]
```

It return error

```
`[]': can't convert Array into Integer (TypeError)
```

How I convert index to integer.

Ps. strInput={1,2,3,4,5} / subInput={3}

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
 puts scores[index.first]
```

Because `index` is an array. Looking at your attempt it seems to me `scores` is also an array. [*`Arrays` are ordered, integer-indexed collections of any object*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html). You can access the Array elements via the `Integer` indexes it has. But you put into it `index` which is an `Array`, not the an `Integer` index. So you got the error as *can't convert Array into Integer (TypeError)*.

You could write it

```
strInput.each_index.select{|i| strInput[i] == subInput}.map(&:to_i)
```

as

```
strInput.each_index.select{|i| strInput[i] == subInput}
```

Because you called [`Array#each_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index), so you are passing all the `Integer` indices of the array `strInput`, to the method [`Array#select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-select). Thus there is no need of the final call of the part `map(&:to_i)`.

I would write your code as below using [`Array#index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-find_index)

```
ind = strInput.index { |elem| elem == subInput }    
puts scores[ind]
```